# How to "read" the following graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-functions

The question is the following. How can I  "see" from the following graph, that $f(-1) = f(1)$?

How can I recognize that, exactly?

[image]

Comment: First look at the $x$-axis (the horizontal line in the middle of the figure). Locate the points $x = -1$ and $ x = 1$. See what their corresponding $y$-values are (in this case they are both zero).

Comment: Does there exist a horizontal line that goes through both $(-1,f(-1))$ and $(1,f(1))$?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you'd treat the x-axis as the inputs to the function $f$ and treat the y-axis as the outputs. So to find out what $f(-1)$ is, you'd look along the x-axis until you found -1, then find what y-coordinate corresponds to that input (in this case, f(-1)=0). Then you'd do the same for x=1, which has a corresponding y-coordinate of 0 as well. Since they both have the same y-coordinate, f(-1)=f(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of "$f(-1)=f(1)$" as saying "the height above $-1$ = the height above $1$".

Here, the "height" is the vertical distance above the given point on the horizontal number line, determined by the graph (possibly negative if the graph is below the horizontal number line at that point).

In your case, the graph is actually at height $0$ above $-1$ and at height $0$ above $1$, so they are the same.

You recognize this by seeing that the vertical segments which you mentally draw there are of the same height.

Likewise, you can see that $f(0)$ and $f(3.5)$ are roughly equal since the height of the graph is roughly $1$ at both of these points.